# Advice needed about Facebook's dialog feed, sharer and like buttons

Tags: facebook, dialog, facebook-like, feed, share

I'm totally confused about Facebook's dialog feed, sharer and like buttons (I'm a noob to Facebook and its jargon)

On my website, I would like the following

- to have a button at the top of the page where people can share **my site** to their wall
- to have a button on the the page where users can share **their main homepage** on my site to their wall
- to have a button where users can share **individual items of theirs (events)** to their wall

I've read the sharer button is being phased out in preference to the Like button but I see a problem with the Like button. I think something can only be liked once. A user's event might want to be shared several times (to remind their Fb users of the event)

I've seen the BBC use the dialog feed button to post items to a wall and that looks okay but I couldn't get the popup to work.

my requirements are to have different links for each of the three scenarios I've mentioned, with a different description for each scenario but sharing my site's logo.

I've read so much that I'm now totally confused plus all the APIs that Fb has. It's just crazy (or that's how it seems to me)

If someone could help clear the fog with sound recommendations and some sample code for each button, I would be very grateful.

Thank you.

.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For what your talking about you would want to use the feed dialog. It's flexible enough that you just need to setup your links and pass in some variables.  I don't see the feed dialog being phased out as you mentioned they serve different purposes.  I think they push the like as it's easier to use and not as likely to be abused.

You'll need to register an application and make sure to initialize the Facebook javascript SDK before you call the below function.  If you're having issues with your popup it's probably due to the fact your FB init process is having issues.  I've added a second function I use to init Facebook.  Both functions use jQuery so you might have to modify if you don't use it.

You can create a pretty generic function like this:

```
$.shareMe = function(myName, myLink, myPicture, myCaption ) {

FB.ui(
  {
    method: 'feed',
    name: myName,
    link: myLink,
    picture: myPicture,
    caption: myCaption

  },
  function(response) {
    if (response && response.post_id) {
      alert('Thanks for Sharing.');
    } else {
      alert('Post was not published.');
    }
  }
);



}
```

and for Facebook initialization:

```
$.initFacebook = function(options){

$('#fb-root').remove();

$('body').append('<div id="fb-root"></div>');

var settings = {

  'appId'       :   null,
  'callback'    :   null,
  'channelUrl'  :   null,
  'status'      :   true,
  'cookie'      :   true,
  'xfbml'       :   true

};

if ( options ) { 
    $.extend( settings, options );
}

if( typeof( xc_app_id ) == 'undefined' ) { window.xc_app_id = settings.appId; }  

window.fbAsyncInit = function() { 

    if(settings.channelUrl==null) {

        FB.init({appId: settings.appId, status: settings.status, cookie: settings.cookie, xfbml: settings.xfbml, oauth: true, authResponse: true }); 

    } else {

        settings.channelUrl=location.protocol+'//'+settings.channelUrl;

        FB.init({appId: settings.appId, status: settings.status, cookie: settings.cookie, xfbml: settings.xfbml, oauth: true, authResponse: true, channelUrl: settings.channelUrl }); 
    }

    if(typeof settings.callback == 'function'){ settings.callback.call(this); }

};

(function() {
var e = document.createElement('script'); 
e.async = true;
e.src = '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
}());

}
```

and to call it you just use $.initFacebook({appId,'yourAppId'}); There are other options there you can lookup in the docs if you need them.

Comment: Cheers man. After posting, I went for a long walk and thought over what I had read. I decided that the feed was the best way for the different events a user may have plus to post their homepage to their wall. To post my site in general to their wall, I'll go with Like. I'll see how that all works out. Thanks for the code. Most helpful. And yes, I have an ID already and I use JQuery.

Comment: The feed is very flexible and with a bit of code you can get a lot of use out of it. Good luck with your program.